# Allow run /sbin/ifconfig to user

Tags: security, permissions, groups, ifconfig

So, I want to allow some user to execute ifconfig. I'd created a special group "if" and done user to own this group. And now I'm going to do "**chown root:if ifconfig**".

But I think: What wrong thing can happen when i change group from root to if? Is there a software which uses ifconfig, running from non-root, but in root group?

Answer (score 2):

Any user can execute `ifconfig`. The problem is that usually you want `ifconfig` to be executed with root permissions, so that you can temporarily change your system configuration. Changing the group of the binary (and having to play with setuid) is **not** the way to do this.

Execute `visudo` and add the line

```
%if   ALL=(ALL) /sbin/ifconfig
```

to the end of the file.

That will let users in group `if` execute `sudo ifconfig` with any arguments they like so that they can temporarily change your system configuration.